# PostgreSQL Connection Error once in a while

Tags: postgresql

Once in a while I face these errors in Postgres.

1. `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

   and
2. `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`

My database will work when I restart the server after getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could post more about your setup - language and libraries (I suppose it's Java and JDBC), server version, what's its purpose (development or production) etc.

The second error you get is very clear - you exceed the configured number of connections to the server. Check the ["max_connections"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) parameter in the server's configuration and increase it if you have the resources.

The first error AFAICS is a general connection error. I have no idea what could cause this (save for the server crash which I doubt is the case).